# Wisp spawn conditions in Thaumcraft 4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

What are the conditions to spawn wisps in Thaumcraft 4? I have a magical biome, do i need a specific light level or anything? I am thinking of a Witchcraft circle that will contain them, is there a better method for spawning them? Platforms in the magical biome maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's a wisp spawner beneath the obsidian alters Thuamcraft adds, just under the area of the chest and node above it. If you have access to a Distortion focus, you should be able to pick up the spawner and bring it back to a more appropriate location, though I'm not sure what the rules are for wisps to spawn (never seen one spawn in the day, at least).